Am I able to put an old SSD on a new PC? Both running Windows 10
I recently bought a new second-hand (stock) PC. It has a 256 GB SSD. I want to import my data from my old PC to my new PC. My old system has 1 SSD and 2 HDDs. (both of the systems are Windows 10).
I have some questions:

If I put my old SSD and HDD into my new PC, do I get all my data back? Will I miss anything?
Am I able to open my applications and games or do I have to download them again?
Because both SSDs have Windows 10 on them. If both of them are included in the system, will there be a problem?

If there's anything I need to do, please tell me.

This can be done, but it's not as simple as installing the OS drive from the old PC into the new PC since the old PC's OS must first be generalized prior to doing so; this is one of several reasons why user data should always be stored on a partition other than C: by going to each user's data directories' Properties → Tab: Location within %UserProfile% [Documents, Downloads, etc.] and moving each to a partition other than C:.

(Cont'd...) Once done on the old PC: Capture a WIM of its OS partition from WinRE as a backup image (generalizing an OS also removes all users IIRC) → Boot back to Windows on the old PC and generalize the OS via SysPrep /Generalize /Shutdown → Once it shut downs, remove the drive prior to booting again, installing it in the new PC → Immediately after OOBE, install CPU chipset drivers → Reboot → Install all other drivers via Windows Update

Thank you sooo much guys for answering. but these ways are very hard and i dont understand. i think its better that i transfer my important things like pictures, musics and projects to an USB and then attach the old SSD and HDD. and i will download the apps again(my data still remains because of accounts) i think this is better. btw Thank You for sharing answers

BTW, you can put some of the extra drives inside the new PC,  if they fit and are compatible, or use one or more external USB enclosures.
